# Combining find and unrar commands

Tags: macos, terminal, find, unrar

I was trying to combine find and unrar commands in macOS but I got some strange results. The command was:

`find /Users/priit/Downloads/Show/ -name "*.rar" -execdir unrar -r -o- "{}" /users/priit/Movies \;`

By running the command I started to get weird outputs from Terminal about unable to extract files or permission denied from /Users/Priit/.wine and other strange locations. After that I added "e" to the unrar command and then it worked fine and extracted all rar files to Movies directory.

Why did the command give me errors from directories which weren't even included in the find directory? Why did adding "e" to the unrar command fix it?

Thanks!